# Why does this Oracle Regular Expression match on newlines?

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a regular expression that is looking for characters that don't match our white-list of valid characters. Effectively this is looking for bad data in a text column. It seems to be matching on newlines:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (text_col, '[^A-Za-z0-9()\\*+=.,:\/!%#\n\r&''\"@?\ -]+')
          AS match_text
  FROM text_table
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (text_col, '[^A-Za-z0-9()\\*+=.,:\/!%#\n\r&''\"@?\ -]+')
```

Why are rows that contain all valid characters being returned and the match_text is just a newline in those cases (or multiple new lines)?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would supply some data examples, both for rows which should and should not match. Thanks.

Comment: 'abc?' should match, 'abc¿' should not.  The only real problem is the newlines.

Comment: Maybe try \x0a and \x0d for newline instead of (or in addition to) \n and \r?

Comment: just tried this based on your suggestion: [^A-Za-z0-9()\\*+=.,:\/!%#\x0a\x0d&''\"@?\ -]+ still no luck.

Comment: Instead of \x0a, \x0d, \n, and \r, perhaps you could try `[:space:]`. This matches "Space characters (nonprinting), such as carriage return, newline, vertical tab, and form feed".

Comment: That looks like it works. if you write it up as an answer i'll accept, thanks!

Comment: FYI, this will only get the first substring that matches this regex.

Comment: that's fine for my purposes I really only want to know if there is a match. getting the first substring is a little bonus and helps me find what the bad data is.

Comment: Probably just my ignorance of regex's showing, but doesn't the `^` as the first character of the class mean "match everything except the characters which follow"? So I would expect neither `abc?` or `abc¿` to match as they both contain characters which should be excluded. ??? I guess my question is, what would you expect REGEX_SUBSTR to return for `abc¿`?

Comment: you are correct in regards to the ^ however; there is no match within abc? because all characters are allowed. ¿ is not allowed so that will match.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[:space:]` instead of the escaped newline/carriage return characters. It matches "Space characters (nonprinting), such as carriage return, newline, vertical tab, and form feed". [Reference](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html)

You should end up with something like:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9()\\*+=.,:\/!%#[:space:]&''\"@?\ -]+
```

Comment: This works. It ends up not-matching on more than the original desire (ie: tabs etc) but for my purposes that's ok for now. Ideally I'd like to come up with a solution that matches for tabs but not \n or \r

Comment: Let's concat the characters we need into the regex then. `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (text_col, '[^A-Za-z0-9()\\*+=.,:\/!%#\n\r&''\"@?\ -'||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||']+')
          AS match_text
      FROM text_table
     WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (text_col, '[^A-Za-z0-9()\\*+=.,:\/!%#\n\r&''\"@?\ -'||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||']+')`

Comment: I haven't figured out why yet but this yields the oracle error : [Error] Execution (11: 60): ORA-12728: invalid range in regular expression

Comment: Oops, it's probably because it sees it as "space through character 10", which would be an invalid range. Move the hyphen to the end, right before the closing bracket.

Comment: Yep that works. I ended up with the regex `"[^A-Za-z0-9()\\*+=.,:\/!%#\n\r&''\"@?'||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||'\ -]+"`

Comment: oops actually this -> `[^A-Za-z0-9()\\*+=.,:\/!%#&''\"@?'||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||'\ -]+`